# Creating a Function or For Loop for Repetitive Task

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops, na

I have a dataset where I need to replace certain values in different columns with NA. The values that should be NA change in some columns due to the data being from a survey with different amount of possible answers. I know how to change the values like this:

```
ayw <- ayw %>% 
  mutate(ExperienceWMentorSRP_01 = ifelse(ExperienceWMentorSRP_01 == 5, NA, ExperienceWMentorSRP_01))
```

or like this:

```
ayw$ExperienceWMentorSRP_01 <- replace(ayw$ExperienceWMentorSRP_01, ayw$ExperienceWMentorSRP_01 ==5, NA)
```

So, there are some sections where I repeat this line of code (just different number after the underscore) for more than a dozen times. I feel like there is a more efficient way of doing this without having to change the column names manually everytime.

I tried making a function:

```
na.fun <- function(dataset, column, nanumber){
              dataset$column[dataset$column == nanumber] = NA
          }

na.fun(ayw, ExperienceWMentorSRP_01, 5)
```

but I get the following error:

! Assigned data `<lgl>` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 155 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 0 rows.

I think I might be going in the wrong direction. I would still need to write it n times anyway unless I make a loop work. And I've tried doing it, as well. Like this:

```
  for (row in mentorset){  #used `select() %>%` to make this subset(mentorset)so I didn't mess anything else
      for (col in row){
         ifelse(col == 5, NA, col)
      }
  }
```

But when I try to save the result each time using `mentorset <-`  and printing the result, it ends up with a data frame with only one value, e. g. '4'. I assume it saves the last iteration of the loop, and that's the reason.

How could I solve this problem? Am I better off just writing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataset$column` is looking for a column literally named `column`, not named for the symbol you passed to it (see [Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a character value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222286/3358272) and [The difference between bracket [ ] and double bracket [[ ]] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/3358272)). You're getting into the realm of non-standard-evaluation (NSE), which can be done but is often fraught with peril and difficult debugging ... though if you must, look at the `tidyselect` package and http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html.

FYI, the `lgl` error you're receiving is because `dataset$column` is returning `NULL`, as in

```r
mtcars$DOES_NOT_EXISTS
# NULL
```

If you can accept using quoted column names, as in `na.fun(ayw, "Experience", 5)`, then try

```r
na.fun <- function(dataset, column, nanumber){
  dataset[[ column ]][ dataset[[ column ]] == nanumber ] <- NA
  dataset
}
```

Note that your function appears to want to work by side-effect, hoping that the change will reside in the data outside of the function ... with few exceptions, this will not happen, R tends to be copy-on-write (not referential semantics). This means that the moment you change the values within the column, the `dataset` as seen inside `na.fun` is now a *copy* of `ayw` outside of the call, and therefore `ayw` is unchanged.

To fix this, we do two things: return the `dataset` *inside* the function (see my code above), and capture the results *outside* of it

```r
ayw <- na.fun(ayw, "ExperienceWMentorSRP_01", 5)
```

(notice the quotes around the variable name)

Comment: Your code for the function worked as intended, thank you! Now if I wanted to do a loop with this function, is it possible? To illustrate what I mean: for (i in mentorset){
  ayw <- na.fun(ayw, "MentorComp_[i]", 5)
}
I know it's wrong, but I just wanted to give an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `"MentorComp_[i]"` is just a string, it is not going to be indexed like I think you intend. You might do something like `for (cn in grep("MentorComp_", names(ayw), value=TRUE)) ayw <- na.fun(ayw, cn, 5)`, that assumes `5` for each column.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but that's amazing, it worked! Thank you so much! I assume grep() was the key here? I looked it up briefly to see that it's about pattern matching, which makes a lot of sense, even though I don't fully understand how it works. I'm still relatively new to all R can do. Anyway, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `grep` is a "swiss army knife" of tools (along with `grepl`): `grep` can return integer indices from within the `x=` vector or it can return the values themselves with `value=TRUE`; there are definitely other ways to get at the same thing.